# how to make vertical middle at bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on Bootstrap 3 framework. At one stage, I've to make vertical align middle at some columns. So, I've applied a custom CSS class like:

```
.valign {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
```

It works when I've only one row. But, when I've multiple row one after another, this don't work. Look at my fiddle please: http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/6mM8G/

I want, at the left side the `<label></label>` should be vertically middle in perspective to input field/select box. `The <p>This will define your Personality</p>` should be vertically aligned too along to select box. But, everything has broken down(for example, "Write Your Name:" and input field was one row which is now broken; "This will define your Personality" text was on right side which is now on left side after breaking down etc) when I use custom class to the columns for removing float and making `display: inline-block`

So, How can I make my `<label></label>` and `<p></p>` of left columns to `vertical: middle`?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use bootstrap classes? For example you can use [Horizontal form](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal) and it might help you achieve exactly what you need.

Here is a code that appeares on their website witch could help you:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```